# Java Checkbox Action

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, actionevent

I have a check box and when I create an Action script from the Netbeans' design, it creates a function like;

```
private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            total=8.99f;
            xc = "XCheese";
            exTop++;
            calculateTotal(total);
            updateTextArea();

}
```

This works perfectly, but I want to set everything to zero when the jCheckBox1 is unchecked, if I uncheck it the way the code is now, no changes appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an sample of code. Hope it will help you.

```
private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
            if(checkBox.isSelected() ){
                   total=8.99f;
                   xc = "XCheese";
                   exTop++;
                   calculateTotal(total);
                   updateTextArea();
            }else{
                   // set everything zero here.
            }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Basically, the `ActionListener` will be called when ever the check box is selected (checked) or unselected (unchecked).  You need to check the state of the check box when ever the method is called.

Take a look at [`AbstractButton#isSelected`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected%28%29) which will tell you the (in this case) the checked state of the `JCheckBox`

Comment: What is the method equivalent to isNotSelected?

Comment: lol duuuh, it is a boolean so it would be isSelected()==false